# How to apply CSS class to PHP variable in an If...else Statement

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have very little experience at programming and am trying to edit a .php file in a Wordpress theme so please bear that in mind as I try to explain my dilemma.

I currently have this code in the theme that calculates the average score from 1 to 10 and displays the `$average` to the user in stars.

```
if( !function_exists('reviews_rating_display') ){
    function reviews_rating_display( $average ){
        if( empty( $average ) ){
            $average = 0;
        }
        $stars = array();
        if( $average < 0.5 ){
            for( $i=0; $i<10; $i++ ){
                $stars[] = '<i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>';
            }
        } elseif( $average < 1 ){
            $stars[] = '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
            for( $i=0; $i<10; $i++ ){
                $stars[] = '<i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>';
            }
        } else{
            $flag = false;
            for( $i=1; $i<=10; $i+=0.5 ){
                if( $i <= $average ){
                    if( floor( $i ) == $i ){
                        $stars[] = '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
                    }
                } else{
                    if( !$flag ){
                        if( floor( $i ) == $i ){
                            $stars[] = '<i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>';
                        }
                        $flag = true;
                    } else{
                        if( floor( $i ) == $i ){
                            $stars[] = '<i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        echo join( "", $stars);
    }
}
```

However, I'm looking to display the `$average` as just a number.

If I leave the code as this

```
if( !function_exists('reviews_rating_display') ){
    function reviews_rating_display( $average ){
        if( empty( $average ) ){
            $average = 0;
        }
        echo number_format((float)$average, 1, '.', '');
    }
}
```

It displays the score as a number and not stars, which is what I want. But I'd like to apply CCS classes to the score with an if else loop.

```
If $average is <6, bad score
If $average is >6 but <8, okay score
If $average is >8, excellent score
```

And I would be applying these classes based on what the score is.

```
.bad-score {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #ff0000;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    float: right;
}

.excellent-score {
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #66cc33;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    float: right;
}

.ok-score {
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #ffcc33;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Next time, please use the "code"-tag. not the "quote"-tag.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
function reviews_rating_class($average) {
    if($average > 8) {
        return 'excellent-score';
    } else if($average <= 8 && $average >= 6) {
        return 'ok-score';
    } else {
        return 'bad-score';
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe show how to include it in html `<div class="<?php the_function(); ?>">`

Comment: Good point, but then better `<div class="<?php echo reviews_rating_class($average); ?>">`

Comment: I'm still confused, what would be the full code? I've tried these suggestions but haven't had any success